# Team Services CI Xcode task package missing build folder in iOS IPA?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I made an iOS app using Ionic Framework and created a CI build in team services with their hosted mac. After it successfully archives and packages the app with Xcode on the hosted mac, I can retrieve the .ipa file from the artifacts. However, it does not work and upon comparison with a working .ipa (from manually archiving in Xcode) it appears it is missing the build folder entirely.

My CI build tasks are as follows:

1. Install apple cert / provisioning profile
2. Npm task that runs `npm install` for the dependencies / node modules
3. Npm task that runs `install -g npm` (this step and the following were to fix an issue with npm on the hosted mac)
4. Npm task that runs `install npm@latest`
5. Ionic Build task that runs `cordova platform add ios` which creates the iOS platform folder
6. Xcode build task that packages the app

All of these run successfully but create an ipa file that does not open or run.

[Here is an image of the CI build with the Xcode build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyM2Z.png)

I have tested all of the steps individually, and the Ionic Build task does create the iOS platform folder that contains the .xcworkspace, which I can manually archive in Xcode successfully. I believe it is an issue with export options since I am using "Automatic" for export options. If I try to change that to "Specify" and give it a parameter of "ad hoc" or "app-store" the task fails with the error:

> Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""TestApp.app" requires
>   a provisioning profile."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="TestApp.app" requires a provisioning
>   profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the
>   "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property
>   list.}

despite it correctly installing a provisioning profile.

For reference, this uses Xcode 9.2

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (Remove personal information)?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT [Put the Xcode archive log in here](https://provisionsgroup-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/matt_west/EpnkU5u1761At9N2VdhzU_YB7BCVTbTVxEPqJ3JI0bV2_w?e=dkhMXK) this is the log for when the CI build succeeds and creates the .ipa, but it is always missing the "build" folder in the "www" folder inside the ipa

Comment: What're commands if you do it in local? How about using Cordova Build task?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Locally I just use the Xcode IDE and archive then export it with "app-store" option (vsts task does the same). Xcode IDE running an archive/export copies over the "build" folder from "www" as well as the index.html, but vsts task does not include any of those in the ipa. Added a build.json to my project so the Cordova build task runs, will update with the results.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Cordova build task ran successfully and created the .ipa, but just like the xcode task the .ipa it produced does not contain the "build" folder or index.html inside the "www" folder, so the ipa does not work

Comment: Which option did you choose when export from Xcode manually?